# Как бесплатно скачать php 8 в ampps?

Tags: php, wamp

Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу бесплатно скачать php 8 в ampps.
Вместо кнопки install выходит buy now.

**Вот скриншот:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переходи на OpenServer ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Я скачал open server, но оно не устанавливается (⊙ˍ⊙)

Comment: от имени админа ставь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ничего не помогло. Open Server поставил. Только с другого сайта. :)